# UML use case diagram consisting approval mechanism

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

I need to draw a use case diagram including multiple actors. I've drawn the scenario with sequence diagram below. How can I draw it as a use case diagram and write it in text form ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a use case diagram with three use cases:

1. Act1
2. Act2/3/4
3. Act5

The three columns of text in your diagram could serve as the textual form of these use cases.

You can't specify the order of the use cases in a use case diagram. You could use your sequence diagram for this purpose and/or you could use pre- and postconditions (e.g. the precondition of Act2/3/4 is the completion of Act1). Personally, I prefer an activity diagram (see [my white paper](http://www.admiraalit.nl/admiraal/WhichUMLmodels.pdf), figure 5).

Alternatively, if each actor has an inbox of tasks to do, you could add an extra step at the end of each use case, stating 'The system adds tasks X to the inbox of actor Y'.

Answer (score 2):

You should not start with a SD in your design. Actors do not interchange messages directly (well, they talk or hit each other  the one or other way). Instead they use systems to interact (so the system can support the interaction). For that you need to know what the added values of your system is. Some of the enumerated points can directly be written as UC. Eg.  `Approve request`. Others like `Fills request form...` are possibly `File request`. It's not to guess what `Saves` means (you  probably need to think over it). So place your actors in a diagram and connect them with bubbles that represent added value. Just as precaution: don't try starting functional decomposition. Don't use include/extend. Just place bubbles for the added values you find. There also should only be one actor connected with a use case. It's possible to connect secondary actors, but then you need to explain how you mark them (e.g. with a `<<use>>` stereotyped association).

Only when you have finished this UC synthesis, you can start creating classes which function as counterpart to the single actors. So your SD will start with an actor sending a message to an instance, doing some more messaging and coming back to the actor finally.

I'd recommend you google for Iconix. They have a very neat methodology constructed how you can use UML to design systems. Nothing is set in concrete anywhere. But some landmarks are used by almost all establish methodologies.

Comment: Request firstly goes to Treasure Unit, then after approval request goes to Audit Unit, then after this approval it goes to CFO, then after approval it goes again to Treasure Unit. How can I show this sequence of approval and multiple actors in use case diagram ?

Comment: You do NOT show it. UC are not about sequence. The UC here is likely `Approve request` where you describe the steps inside the UC. It's not that each single step is a UC. The UC is the added value (so that should be clear from the type of request; maybe `Approve credit` if that's the request; I don't know your domain).

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion about diagram is caused by absence of actual use cases. Just do it vice versa, write down use cases (it looks like you already finished most of work to understand the process) and you will have a vision about diagram. Or at least more specific question.

Keep in mind that diagram is merely a representation, use cases - this is where actual creation takes place. Diagram derivates from use cases and complements them.